# How to handle XMLRPC::FaultException errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling

I have a list of pingbacks that need to be sent for each post. It looks something like this:

```
def send_trackback
  #do stuff
  begin
    Pingback::Client.new.ping(source_uri, target_uri)
    trackback.status = 1
    trackback.save
  rescue
    trackback.status = 2
    trackback.save
    nil
  end
end
```

Here is the full error:

```
  XMLRPC::FaultException (The specified target URL cannot be used as a target. It either doesn&#8217;t exist, or it is not a pingback-enabled resource.):
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:67:in `block in send_trackback'
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:62:in `send_trackback'
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:8:in `pingback'

Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.1ms)
Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (0.8ms)
Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (4.6ms)
```

Status starts out as being 0, but if the ping back fails that's okay but I want status set 2 and I want it just to keep going not throw an error to rails. If it is a success, I want status set to 1.

Shouldn't the begin - rescue blocks handle this? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

That should work. It looks like the exception is getting triggered in pingback/send_trackback and not send_pingback

Comment: Is it possible that rails is caching things on it's end. It seems like I change something on development, pull to production and it doesn't work. Wait a couple hours and it works. That's got to be caching!